# How to force eager loading with CrudRepository in spring-data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have an entity containing a `List` that is thus `lazy` loaded by default:

```
interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar") //lazy by default
    private List<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    //some more
}
```

**Question**: How can I force eager loading when executing `repository.findOne(id)`?

Comment: I know I can force the `eager` mode like this. But I want to stick to the `lazy` default and just force eager on all lists on one specific select.

Comment: Well then, If you're using criteria in DAO you can force fetch type by
`criteria.setFetchMode("bars", FetchMode.EAGER)`

Comment: or you can use `MyEntity p = (MyEntity) sess.get(MyEntity.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(p.getBars());`

Comment: So that would imply writing my own criterea. Which is fine in general, but I hope spring-data would bring something for this.

Comment: you can write a query @Query("select m from MyEntity m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.bars")
    MyEntity findOne(Long id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this too and as I'm calling the dao inside a service object that is insise a transaction I call call the get method so no exception and I was able to fetch the records. 
Something like in java 8:

```
public ProductEntity findProduct(int id) {
    ProductEntity p = productRepository.findOne(id);
    p.getPresentations().stream().count();
    return p;
}
```

`p.getPresentations().stream().count();` will force the fetch, I know is not a clean way to do it but it gets the job done in the mean time

Comment: This solution generate more then one query.

Answer (score 20):

You can force eager fetch writing custom HQL query with `left join fetch`, eg:

```
interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Query("select e from MyEntity e left join fetch e.bar b where e.id = ?1")
    MyEntity findOne(long id)
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Change your mapping from

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar") //lazy by default
```

To

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //lazy by default
```

Comment: To quote myself: "I know I can force the eager mode like this. But I want to stick to the lazy default and just force eager on [...] one specific select"